# Angularjs - Call function before page refresh?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If a user hits refresh, I want to call an angular service to save their work, and upon completion of the save (asynchronous call), only then should the page refresh. How can I achieve this?

So far I've tried calling the save service outside angular, using window.onbeforeunload. But no luck. Any general advice on how to approach this? How does Angular handle page refreshes?

Answer (score 2):

there is an event called `$routeChangeStart`

you can simply bind the handler when the route is about to change, it should work also for refreshing the page

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
    //callback
});
```

Comment: I am trying it like this, but no luck. What am I doing wrong?


`app.run( function($rootScope, myService) {
 $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("saving.....");
  myService.save();
 });
});`

Comment: I believe, this only works when user navigates between 2 views. It done not work for page reload. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks in advance.